# Like button does not work with a 301 redirection

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

For practical reasons, I use a 301 redirection at the loading of my page (URL rewriting). My Facebook button doesn't work on this page. The count works, but nothing appears on my Facebook page.

I think that the Facebook bot can't get access to the content of my page. How can it be made to work?

Comment: It depends how you handle the redirect. Facebook scrapes information for a like button by viewing the source of the URL the button points to.