# Facebook like counter reset - how can we restore the count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, dotnetnuke

Please help,

I'm using a facebook like button with counter at http://mysterium.co.il home page.
This is the button source:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysterium.co.il" data-send="false" data-    layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" style="text-align: left;"></div>
```

It got up to 130 likes after few month.
Suddenly it reset to 0.

The site is built with Dotnetnuke 7.02.
The only change we did there at Site Aliases was to redirect 'www.mysterium.co.il' request to 'mysterium.co.il'.

How can we get back the count?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that fb does not update an indexed url with likes to the new url the 301 redirects to.There is a similar question with a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691311/facebook-like-count-resets-after-a-301-redirection). A second question with a solution is [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o).

Comment: Thanks, I've reviewed both solutions but current case is not the same.
I've just added that if a user is navigating with www.mysterium.co.il it will be redirected to mysterium.co.il (the original against fb). Users navigating to mysterium.co.il gets no redirection, but why the fb like counter that always pointed to mysterium.co.il reset? that's the big question.

Comment: Did you switch from HTTP to HTTPS? I think that'll do it.